# How to reduce compression time and maintain quality of video at same time, FFMPEG library android

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, mobile-ffmpeg

i am using FFMPEG library to compress video and able to achieve a normal quality also. But if i try improving the resolution, compression time increases. The output should be such where a standard video output is achieved, along with very high quality video, maintaining the aspect ratio as well. Below is the code i am using, please suggest me ways to improvise this. Help is appreciated. Thanks

```
                MediaModifierTypes.VIDEO_COMPRESS -> return arrayOf(
                    "-y",
                    "-i",
                    videoPath,
                    "-vf",
                    "scale=1280:-1",
                    "-vcodec",
                    "mpeg4",
                    "-b:v",
                    "2M",
                    "-b:a",
                    "48000",
                    outputFilePath
                )
```